# PHPexcel columns width

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHPexcel saving modified excel file with columns sized to half of the original width. Is there any global settings or method to tell PHPexcel "left column width as it is" ?

Original columns doesn't have the same width. I don't want to set each column manually.

Comment: PHPExcel will save columns with the original width if the original width was read from the original file, and has not been changed in the code. If you're reading an actual spreadsheet file rather than html or csv, then using the readdataonly setting when reading the file will not read the original widths, otherwise they should remain unchanged

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using 05featuredemo and 07reader examples. If I use 05featuredemo.xlsx, there is no problem, but with my own xlsx each column has half width (for example: before 64, after save 32; or 108 -> 54 ...). Now I found second problem. If there are many data (don't know the size) in excel sheet, it will create two sheets with the same content. I tried this with 05featuredemo.xlsx with content repeated 8 times in row and row repeated 8 times.

Comment: Please provide an example of this second problem (upload to phpexcel site) as I have never seen a working example of a file that creates multiple worksheets with the same data

Comment: @MarkBaker now you have example [here](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/20208) . But what about the first issue? Have you ever seen it? I can solve it by make source's columns double width, but better to know right solution :-)

Comment: I haven't seen the first issue before, and as column widths are left unchanged unless they're explicitly changed, I can't particularly understand it either